# pip3 requirements.txt full of garbage

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 and whenever I do `pip3 freeze > requirement.txt` I get the following huge list. From my research, it seems as though the dependencies for certain installations end up being in this list.

My question is, how can I remove most of this garbage or at least uninstall everything to start fresh again. Thanks

> 

```
apturl==0.5.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
attrs==19.1.0
backcall==0.1.0
bleach==3.1.0
Brlapi==0.6.6
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
command-not-found==0.3
cryptography==2.1.4
cupshelpers==1.0
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.3.2
defer==1.0.6
defusedxml==0.5.0
distro-info==0.18
docopt==0.6.2
entrypoints==0.3
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Caching==1.6.0
gunicorn==19.9.0
httplib2==0.9.2
idna==2.8
ipykernel==5.1.0
ipython==7.3.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.4.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jedi==0.13.3
Jinja2==2.10
jsonschema==3.0.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.4
jupyter-console==6.0.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
keyring==10.6.0
keyrings.alt==3.0
kiwisolver==1.0.1
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.10.6
lazr.restfulclient==0.13.5
lazr.uri==1.0.3
louis==3.5.0
macaroonbakery==1.1.3
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.0.3
mistune==0.8.4
nbconvert==5.4.1
nbformat==4.4.0
netifaces==0.10.4
nltk==3.4
notebook==5.7.4
numpy==1.16.2
oauth==1.0.1
olefile==0.45.1
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.3.4
pexpect==4.6.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==5.1.0
pipreqs==0.4.9
praw==6.1.1
prawcore==1.0.1
prometheus-client==0.6.0
prompt-toolkit==2.0.9
protobuf==3.0.0
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pycairo==1.16.2
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.73
Pygments==2.3.1
pygobject==3.26.1
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.1.2
pyparsing==2.3.1
pyRFC3339==1.0
pyrsistent==0.14.11
python-apt==1.6.3+ubuntu1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-debian==0.1.32
pytz==2018.3
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==3.12
pyzmq==18.0.0
qtconsole==4.4.3
reportlab==3.4.0
requests==2.21.0
requests-unixsocket==0.1.5
scour==0.36
SecretStorage==2.3.1
Send2Trash==1.5.0
simplejson==3.13.2
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.12.0
system-service==0.3
systemd-python==234
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.4.2
textblob==0.15.3
tornado==6.0.1
traitlets==4.3.2
ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0
ufw==0.35
unattended-upgrades==0.1
update-checker==0.16
urllib3==1.24.1
usb-creator==0.3.3
virtualenv==16.4.3
wadllib==1.3.2
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==0.55.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
widgetsnbextension==3.4.2
xkit==0.0.0
yagmail==0.11.214
yarg==0.1.9
zope.interface==4.3.2
```

Comment: Where is the garbage? Everything looks like well formed printables too me.

Comment: @jww I should have specified that I'm using this list to host a webapp on Heroku. The problem is that some of the items on this list, such as apturl is not installable; or at least I get an error saying that version 0.5.2 of apturl is not found when I attempt to install everything on this list.

If I produced this same list using pip (instead of pip3) the list is much much shorter and cleaner.

Comment: I'd suggest making a virtualenv to isolate yourself from the operating system's packages

Answer (score 0):

This print is for all the packages you´d installed in the Python version you're using. The correct way to do that is using a virtualenv that use only the packages that are really neccesary to the project.